# Is there a way to be notified of status changes in Google AI Platform training jobs without polling the REST API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

Right now I monitor my submitted jobs on Google AI Platform (formerly ml engine) by polling the [job REST API](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs). I don't like this solution for a few reasons:

1. Awareness of status changes is often delayed or missed altogether if the interval between status changes is smaller than the monitoring polling rate
2. Lots of unnecessary network traffic
3. Lots of unnecessary function invocations

I would like to be notified as soon as my training jobs complete. It'd be great if there is some way to assign hooks or callbacks to run when the job status changes.

I've also considered adding calls to cloud functions directly within the training task python package that runs on AI Platform. However, I don't think those function calls will occur in cases where the training job is shutdown unexpectedly, such as when a job is cancelled or forced to end by GCP.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Stackdriver sink to read the logs and send it to Pub/Sub. From Pub/Sub, you can connect to a bunch of other providers:

### 1. Set up a Pub/Sub sink

Make sure you have [access to the logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control) and [publish rights to the topic you desire](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control) before you get started. Follow the instructions for setting up a Stackdriver -> Pub/Sub sink. You’ll want to use this query to limit the events only to Training jobs:

```
resource.type = "ml_job"
resource.labels.task_name = "service"
```

Note that [Stackdriver can further limit down the query](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/basic-queries). For example, you can limit to a particular Job by adding a condition like `resource.labels.job_id` = "..." or to a certain event with a filter like `jsonPayload.message` : "..."

### 2. Respond to the Pub/Sub message

In order to tell what changed, the recipient of the Pub/Sub message can either query the job status from the ml.googleapis.com API or read the text of the message

#### Reading state from ml.googleapis.com

When you receive the message, make a call to `https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/<project_id>/jobs/<job_id>` to get the Job information, replacing [project_id] and [job_id] in the URL with the values of resource.label.project_id and resource.label.job_id from the Pub/Sub message, respectively.

The returned Job object contains a field `state` that, naturally, tells the status of the job.

#### Reading state from the message text

The Pub/Sub message will contain a string telling what happened to the job. You probably want behavior when the job ends. Look for these strings in jsonPayload.message:

- "Job completed successfully."
- "Job cancelled."
- "Job failed."

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. Reading logs and publishing to pub/sub would definitely be one way to go about this. I'm going to take this to mean that ml-engine has no built-in hooks that can be triggered by state changes.

Comment: @EdmundRosewright Did you figure out any other solution, like having the job itself publish a pubsub message when it completes? I am trying to do exactly the same thing but haven't gotten it to work yet.

Comment: So far I think that @htappen 's solution is the best we can do right now. It is working well for me (although it was a pain to implement). I've previously tried what you're suggesting. Unfortunately, any code within the actual job is not guaranteed to run in the event of a job cancellation or sudden crash. On top of that, it would only allow me to monitor the internal state of my app, but not the actual AI Platform [job state](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#State)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a Terraform module as @htappen said. I'm happy if it would help you. But my real hope is that Google updates AI Platform with the same feature.

https://github.com/sfujiwara/terraform-google-ai-platform-notification

Answer (score 0):

I think you can programmatically publish a PubSub message at the end of your training job code. Something like this:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

# publish job complete message
client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic = client.topic_path(args.gcp_project_id, 'topic-name')
data = {
    'ACTION': 'JOB_COMPLETE',
    'SAVED_MODEL_DIR': args.job_dir
}
data_bytes = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
client.publish(topic, data_bytes)
```

Then you can setup a cloud function to be triggered by the same pubsub topic.

Comment: I considered doing something like this but unfortunately it only works if the training code is able to execute all the way to the end. There are many ways for the training job to end abruptly. For example if you cancel the job, or crashes, or if the job is interrupted/preempted by gcp. In these cases the pubsub call may not ever get to execute.

Additionally, this would only allow me to monitor the internal state of my app, but not the actual AI Platform job state.

Comment: @EdmundRosewright. That makes sense. I suppose you could wrap your training code in a try/except but that doesn't give fine grained notifications of job state. I wish AI Platform Training would publish job state events to a predefined PubSub topic automatically for just this reason.

Comment: Ya I agree it would be a huge improvement if they automatically published the job state events to a PubSub topic. And wrapping the entire training code in a try/except helps mitigate crashes due to errors from within the program. But it doesn't help with crashes from outside, such as an out of memory crash or job cancellation. I've also noticed there can be a long delay between when our AI Platform Job starts and our actual training code begins to run as well as between when our code finishes executing and when the Job is actually marked as complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the lack of a callback from the service on a custom TF training job by adding a LamdbaCallback to the fit() call. In the on_epoch method, you could then send yourself a notification on job progress and on_train_end when it finishes.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LambdaCallback

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for the reasons discussed in the comment thread of David Brown's solution.